# UnityObject2.getUnity().SendMessage() method is missed in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer, unity-game-engine, unity-web-player

Dom element  returned by getUnity() not contains SendMessage. How i can use SendMessage in IE?

Update: It's some bug.
http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1051929/webplayer-unityobject2getunitysendmessage-method-i.html